# Accessing a function against another owner in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am having a function called fn_export and its owner is bhist. I am calling this function from ohist user using bhist.fn_export. While calling like this I am facing the below issue.

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "bhist.fn_export", line 442
ORA-06512: at line 20
```

I tried to verify all the tables in that function and I am able to access all those tables from ohist. I have execute grant on bhist.fn_export to ohist. Still I am having this issue. Can any one of you please help in resolving this issue?

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: It seems that an object of another owner is also involved: BDMAPPHIST.FN_EXCEL_EXPORT. I think you need a SELECT grant on this one as well.

Comment: SELECT grant on a function is possible? If so can you help me with sample sql for this grant? grant select on bhist.fn_export to ohist dint work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant `EXECUTE` privilege on this function to `ohist` user.
A syntax is:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON function_name TO username;
```

You can connect as `bhist` user and grant the privilege using:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON fn_export TO ohist;
```

You can also connect as SYS or SYSTEM, and use this command:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON bhist.fn_export TO ohist;
```

See a below simple example (one user is named `TEST` and the other is named `DEV`):

```
SQL> connect test
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> CREATE FUNCTION fn_export RETURN number AS
  2  BEGIN
  3    RETURN 20;
  4  END;
  5  /

Function created.

SQL> connect dev
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> SELECT test.fn_export FROM dual;
SELECT test.fn_export FROM dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "TEST"."FN_EXPORT": invalid identifier


SQL> connect test
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant execute on fn_export to dev;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect dev
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> SELECT test.fn_export FROM dual;

 FN_EXPORT
----------
        20

SQL>
```